# How to download files from Nexus using python

Tags: python, nexus

I'm a beginner to this Nexus. I have an automation requirement that I need to download set of files from a Nexus repo and process those files's contents and generate some output file with the content. So, is that possible to download the files from Nexus using python. I searched for some resources but nothing is working out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [nexus3-cli](https://pypi.org/project/nexus3-cli/) to access the Nexus repositories.

```
pip install nexus3-cli
```

and then use it like this:

```
import nexuscli.nexus_client
import nexuscli.nexus_config
import nexuscli.nexus_http
from nexuscli.api.repository.base_models.repository import Repository


nexus_config = nexuscli.nexus_config.NexusConfig(url=NEXUS_URL, username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)
nexus_client = nexuscli.nexus_client.NexusClient(nexus_config)
nexus_http=nexuscli.nexus_http.NexusHttp(nexus_config)

nexus_repository=Repository(name=NAME_OF_REPOSITORY,nexus_client=nexus_client, nexus_http=nexus_http)

nexus_repository.download(NEXUS_REMOTH_PATH, LOCAL_PATH_TO_SAVE_FILE, flatten=True)
```

Use your repository name, nexus url and username and password in the above code. you should be able to download the file.

Comment: Thank you @parvaneh and  Sorry for the delayed response ... Can you please add **how to list all the assets/items** available in a repository or in specific folder in a repository . Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any other configuration that needs to be done here? I am getting a ```nexuscli.exception.NexusClientInvalidCredentials: Try running `nexus3 login` ``` error. Although my credentials are correct